# Reference UIkit-Components in Javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, getuikit

How do I reference a UIkit Component in Javascript? I made a small example of my problem:

This is the HTML:

```
    <div class="uk-panel">
      <div id="myRadios" data-uk-button-radio>
        <button class="uk-button">Option1</button>
        <button class="uk-button">Option2</button>
        <button class="uk-button">Option3</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <button class="uk-button" onclick="check()">Check Selection</button>
```

And here is the Javascript part:

```
function check() {
  var selected = $('#myRadios').getSelected();
  var selected2 = $('#myRadios').uk('buttonRadio').getSelected();
  // getSelected() is not defined in both!
}
```

I also created this as a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/U4ELL78YSsBbBHiwGnOQ

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIkit seems to only toggle buttons(I don't see any api inside docs), and adds class uk-active to selected buttons. So maybe something like this:

```
$('#myRadios button').on('click', function() {
     var selectedValue = $(this).text();
     console.log(selectedValue);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I thought of this, but this was more like a workaround. UIKit itself has this code block, but I don't know how get access to this on the specific element: `UI.component('buttonRadio', {

        defaults: {
            "target": ".uk-button"
        },

        boot: function() {

        },

        init: function() {

        },

        getSelected: function() {
            return this.find(".uk-active");
        }
    });`

Comment: I also found out that when I initialize the button in js myself and not in html like `UIkit.buttonRadio(UIkit.$('#myRadios'))` then I get a reference of the element with the getSelected function. I want this reference on an already initialized element.

Comment: Only thing Ive found `var button = UIkit.buttonRadio('#myRadios');
console.log(button.getSelected());` I think it's the most resonable way :)

Comment: This seems to work. When I first tested this the click listener was attached multiple times, but I can't reproduce this error atm.

Comment: I tested in my (real) project and it worked. Thank you very much!